# javascript, nested for loop issue

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop

I have an assignment for school where we have to make random edits to a webpage using only javascript, no jquery or css is allowed for the edits. I'm looking to reverse the order of the nav bar, for example change

> home about contact

to

> contact about home

because they are links I had to change the href as well, but I have made a silly mistake somewhere because it is changing everything to home (the the text to "home" and the href to the href i want to use for "home") so I think the problem must be my second for loop or else in the loop, I just can't see where, so any help would be much appreciated!

```
var navIds = ["hHome", "hAbout", "hPlants", "hGarden", "hNews", "hArticle", "hContact"];
var navHref = ["index.html", "about.html", "plants.html", "garden.html", "news.html", "article.html", "contact.html"];
var navText = ["home", "about", "plants", "garden", "news", "article", "contact"];

    function changeNav()
    {
        for(var i=0; i<navIds.length; i++)
        {
            for(var j=navHref.length; j>=0; j= j-1)
            {
                var x = document.getElementById(navIds[i]);
                var y = navHref[j];
                x.setAttribute("href", y);
                x.textContent = navText[j]; 
            }   
        }
   }
```

the vars are just arrays where i stored the ids for what i want to change and the hrefs i want to use and the text i want them to display.

thanks in advance if you can help!!

the html is just a from a free template and isn't mine bar adding an id to the links,

```
 <div id="header">
            <a href="index.html" id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a id="hHome" href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a id="hAbout" href="about.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a id="hPlants" href="plants.html">Plants</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a id="hGarden" href="gardens.html">Gardens</a>
                    </li>       
                    <li class="current">
                        <a id="hNews" href="news.html">News</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="current">
                            <a id="hArticle" href="article.html">Article</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a id="hContact" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="partA">
        <input type="submit" value="PartA" onclick="linkA()"/>
        <input type="submit" value="PartB" onclick="linkB()"/>
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you also post the relevant HTML along with this?

Comment: If there are an equal amount of elements in the lists, you don't need/shouldn't have a nested for-loop

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly, but when i press a button it should swap everything around and display my nav bar in the reverse order

Comment: Just remove the second for-loop and take element at index `i` from all three Arrays.

Comment: This code would be more clear with the use of a `"nav"` object. Take a look into using [Array.prototype.reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) as well for the reversing. I'll write a more detailed answer once I'm free later today.

Comment: Would a simple array.reverse() work or does your requirement need the looping to demonstrate understanding with loops?

Comment: Now i see where you are going with this. Take the element at `i` from the first array, and the elements at position `(navIds.length-1) - i` from the other two.

Comment: cheers for the help! its working for me now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can handle that in one single for-loop..

Maybe you should have a look on the For-In Loop -> https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Heres what i come up with:

```
    for(navs in navIds){
     var html = '<a id="' + navIds[navs] + '" href="' + navHref[navs] + '">' + navText[navs] + '</a>';

     document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend',html);
    }
```

You can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/1tLkz9o2/

Answer (score 0):

As promised, here is how I would approach this problem.

First, condense the multiple arrays into a single array containing `nav` objects.

```
var navElementData = [
    { id: "hHome"   , href: "index.html"  , text: "home"    },
    { id: "hAbout"  , href: "about.html"  , text: "about"   },
    { id: "hPlants" , href: "plants.html" , text: "plants"  },
    { id: "hGarden" , href: "garden.html" , text: "garden"  },
    { id: "hNews"   , href: "news.html"   , text: "news"    },
    { id: "hArticle", href: "article.html", text: "article" },
    { id: "hContact", href: "contact.html", text: "contact" }
];
```

This way, it is clear that each object in the array relates to a single menu item and makes the reversal process easier.

Below I've provided the full working implementation that I will reference.

We now need a function that will actually do the rendering of a single element. I've named it `getNavElement`.

To render these elements to the document, I've created a new generic function named `renderNav` that takes in a container (e.g. a `div`), and some data `navElementData`.

Finally, I've created a simple function that wraps this `renderNav` function named `renderReverseNav` that simply reverses the data before calling `renderNav`.

You can view the working example below. Let me know if you have any questions.

http://jsbin.com/molimawicu/1/edit?html,js,output

```js
// Create a new nav element
function getNavElement(id, href, text) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.id = id;
    element.href = href;
    element.textContent = text;
    element.setAttribute('style', 'margin: 5px');
    return element;
}

// Render the nav element
function renderNav(container, navElementData) {
    // Clear the existing container
    container.innerHTML = '';

    // Map over the data given
    navElementData.map(function(data) {
        // Create a new element
        var element = getNavElement(data.id, data.href, data.text);
        // Append it to the container
        container.appendChild(element);
    });
}

function renderReverseNav(container, navElementData) {
    return renderNav(container, navElementData.reverse());
}

// --- usage ---

var navElementData = [
    { id: "hHome"   , href: "index.html"  , text: "home"    },
    { id: "hAbout"  , href: "about.html"  , text: "about"   },
    { id: "hPlants" , href: "plants.html" , text: "plants"  },
    { id: "hGarden" , href: "garden.html" , text: "garden"  },
    { id: "hNews"   , href: "news.html"   , text: "news"    },
    { id: "hArticle", href: "article.html", text: "article" },
    { id: "hContact", href: "contact.html", text: "contact" }
];

var navContainer = document.getElementById('navContainer');
var revNavContainer = document.getElementById('revNavContainer');

renderNav(navContainer, navElementData);
renderReverseNav(revNavContainer, navElementData);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="navContainer"></div>
  <div id="revNavContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```